# Filter and display Google Map Markers from database based on DropDownList selection in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

in our project we need to show the markers on Google map from the database. we have already got the code in which all the markers are displayed for the the places stored in database. But our aim is somewhat different.We need marker on one place that is selected from the database.to elaborate,if we select an area from the dropdownlist that contains names of areas stored in database,then "only" marker on that place must be displayed.Further,selecting the subarea from dropdownlist2 should zoom the map and display a marker on that subarea.so how do we do that? 
Awaiting your rply.

Answer (score 0):

The best possible and simple way I can think of to solve this issue is to have multiple colored markers for specific region or area you want to make distinction. this would automatically draw a line of difference in between tow area's (If this can also be a solution for you).

For code implementation have a look at this [example](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Google-Maps-V3-Display-Colored-Markers-for-particular-type-of-location.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

we just need to add the following code in the selectedIndexChange event of the DropDownList1 so that it will return the filtered records.

DataTable dt = this.GetData("select [Name], [Latitude], [Longitude] from [MAIN AREA] WHERE [Name] ='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text+"'");

rptMarkers.DataSource = dt;

rptMarkers.DataBind();